# JS: Difference between simple number array and Array.slice()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just wanna ask what's the difference between normal number array:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `[1,2,3,4,5,6].slice();`

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].slice());
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

The result seems to be the same, but something changes. I want to know what exactly it is.

Comment: `.slice()` is used to make a copy of the array.

Comment: @Barmar Can you make a full answer? I will mark it as the best one.

Comment: `.slice()` is used to make a shallow clone of the array which won't reference the original array.

Comment: @Patrickkx What's wrong with the answers you got?

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation on MND to learn about built-in functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice .

Comment: @Barmar I wanna give u some rep coz u were first.

Comment: I have more rep than I know what to do with, I'm OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `slice()` (without arguments) function you create shallow copy of the original array.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
arr === arr; // true
arr === arr.slice(); // false
```

It may be helpful when you want to clone some array, do some operation on it but not modify original one.

Comment: Seems like you are right. Thank you! It explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified. You can also do an exact copy using `.slice()` instead of `.slice(begin, end)`.

```
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
var sliced = a.slice(1,3);

console.log(a);      // [ "zero", "one", "two", "three" ]
console.log(sliced); // [ "one", "two" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array 
So if you pass `begin` & `end` it will return a new array 
For example

`[1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(1,3)` will return `[2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

It will return a new array containing the elements from the given start index up the one right before the specified end index

```
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(2));

// returns 1,2

console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(0,3));

// returns 1,2,3

console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(2,4));

// returns 3,4
```

https://ariya.io/2014/02/javascript-array-slice-vs-splice